# Apache SSL HTTPS Works Only in Chrome

Tags: apache, ssl, next.js, amazon-ec2, https

I have a NextJS server running on aws ec2 ubuntu instance port 3000 and want to redirect traffic from port 443 with Apache to port with NextJS app. I achieved the desired result, but it works only in the Chrome browser.

That's how my Apache config file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_domain_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain_private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_domain_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

These are my last logs from apache:

```
[Thu Jan 25 20:11:21.975521 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2267:tid 140152490424192] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Jan 25 20:11:22.062393 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2367:tid 139778842716032] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 25 20:11:22.062521 2024] [core:notice] [pid 2367:tid 139778842716032] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

When I try to open the domain.com in Chrome it works fine, but any other browser cannot get the response back and waits until ttl expires.

Comment: according to [Mod Proxy Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) you should be putting double quotes around your directives : For example `ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"`

Comment: @Zak I put double quotes around the directives for the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse arguments and it did not help. I still can open the website only in Google Chrome :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple....Other browsers except Chrome by default try to send the request for the example.com to port 80. Therefore I should have been redirecting the traffic from port 80 to 443.

Here is my full configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3000/"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example_private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_example_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```